# variable in variable name for javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variable-names

The command "alert(numOne);" shows f_name. Thus, I want the the last line of the function to become document.f_name.submit(); but my current idea doesn't work. Is there a way to make this happen?

```
    function submitform(e)
{
    var numOne = e.id;
    alert(numOne);
    if (        confirm("Proceed?")){
          document.numOne.submit();
        }

}
```

Comment: `document[numOne].submit()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bracket notation` for this purpose,

```
document[numOne].submit();
```

And your full code would be,

```
function submitform(e) {
  if (confirm("Proceed?")) {
    document[e.id].submit();
  }
}
```